# How to print your function's documentation python

Tags: python, printing

I have been searching for an answer for a lot of time now. Let's say I wrote a function in python and I made a brief documentation of what this function is doing. Is there any way to print the function's documentation from within main? Or from the function itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use **[`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help)** or print the `__doc__`. `help()` prints a more verbose description of an object while `__doc__` holds **only** the documentation string you have defined with triple quotes `""" """` *in the beginning* of your function.

For example, using `__doc__` explicitly on the `sum` built-in function:

```
print(sum.__doc__)
Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
reject non-numeric types.
```

Additionally, since Python first compiles an object and during execution evaluates it you can call `__doc__` within the function with no problems:

```
def foo():
    """sample doc"""
    print(foo.__doc__)

foo()  # prints sample doc
```

and remember, besides functions, modules and classes have a `__doc__` attribute holding their documentation.

Alternatively, using `help()` for `sum`:

```
help(sum)
```

Will print:

```
Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:

sum(iterable, start=0, /)
    Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

    When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
    This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
    reject non-numeric types.
```

gives a bit more information, including the docstring.